# max with dictionaries python, same structure, different output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, dictionary, max

the first structure:

```
dic = {'l':2, 'o':3, 'p':6}

for key in dic:
    total = [dic[key]]
print max(total)
```

the output is 6

second structure:

```
dic = {}
print 'Enter line of text'
line = input('')
words = line.split()
print 'Words', words
print 'Counting'
for word in words:
    dic[word] = dic.get(word,0) + 1
print 'Dictionary of your text', dic

for num in dic:
    total = [dic[num]]
print max(total)
```

output is 1 and mostly 1

Comment: what is  `total = [dic[num]]` supposed to be doing? You only store a single value i.e the last `dic[num]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only ever putting the *last* value in your `total` list:

```
for key in dic:
    total = [dic[key]]
```

This rebinds `total` each time to a new list. This then depends on the order of the dictionary, which is [dependent on the dictionary insertion and deletion history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary).

Just use `max(dic.values())` if you want to know the maximum value.

If you *must* use a loop, then at least append the value to an existing list:

```
total = []
for key in dic:
    total.append(dic[key])

print(max(total))
```

Comment: I really can't see where or why the dictionary values are strings and not integers in the second case? could you help please?

Comment: @Jalanji: that was a mistake on my part.